# how can I get store a value in a variable from a field in mongodb collection using groovy?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I have inserted a new document in my collection successfully. Now I want read the same document and extract its "_id" , store it in a variable to use in my next sampler.My script is failing

```
    import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
    import org.bson.Document;
    import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
    import org.bson.Document;
    import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
    //import java.util.Arrays;

    try {


    MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");

        Document document = new Document("EmployeeOID",12345)
            //.append("EmployeeOID",12345)
            .append("EmployeeName", "Test Automation through Jmeter")
            .append("Employee_Type_OID",4)
            .append("Rank",0)
            .append("Rating",0)
            .append("Score",0)
            .append("Supervisor_OID",56789)
            .append("TRGEmpID","012345T");

        collection.insertOne(document);


    Document result = collection.find(eq("EmployeeOID",12345)).first();

    def ID = result.get("_id").toString()); 
        return "Document inserted"+result.get(ID);

        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
        SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
        SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
    }
```

ERROR:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
startup failed:
Script219.groovy: 31: expecting '}', found ')' @ line 31, column 38.
   def ID = result.get("_id").toString());  
                                        ^
```

Comment: all in error. you have two closing brackets instead of one at the end of this line: `def ID = result.get("_id").toString())`

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
def ID = result.get("_id").toString());
```

to this one:

```
def ID = result.get("_id").toString()
```

if you additionally want to save the value into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you can do it as:

```
vars.put('ID', ID)
```

Once done you will be able to get the value back as `vars.get('ID')` in the JSR223 scripts or just `${ID}` in other test elements

Demo:

[image]

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/)